# Content-Type is overridden by json object

Tags: javascript, json, axios, json-api

I have a Axios interceptor to change the data of a POST request:

```
export default function ({ $axios }) {
  $axios.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
    console.log('req: ', req)
    req.data = {
      data: {
        type: 'user',
        attributes: {
          vendor: 'Facebook',
          code: '**'
        }
      }
    }
    return req
  })

  $axios.setHeader('Accept', 'application/vnd.api+json', [
    'post'
  ])
  $axios.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.api+json', [
    'post'
  ])
}
```

But using this `req.data` changes to content-type to `application/json;charset=UTF-8` causing the back end to return a `415 (Unsupported Media Type)`.

Comment: Well then simply set the header inside the interceptor, like `req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.api+json';`